# What is a "key" without a foreign key restraint?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following table, which enforces a foreign key on `vendor_id`:

```
CREATE TABLE `notes` (
  `vendor_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  KEY `vendor_id` (`vendor_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `notes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`vendor_id`) REFERENCES `title` (`vendor_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I was looking over someone else's table, and it had the `KEY`, but did not show a `CONSTRAINT`, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `notes` (
  `vendor_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  KEY `vendor_id` (`vendor_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What exactly does this mean / do to have a `KEY` without anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`KEY` is a synonym for `INDEX`, so in this case, `vendor_id` has had an index created on it, but has not specifically been defined as the table's `PRIMARY KEY`, which would enforce uniqueness.

From the [MySQL `CREATE TABLE` docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html):

> KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX. The key attribute PRIMARY KEY can also be specified as just KEY when given in a column definition. This was implemented for compatibility with other database systems.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [§12.1.14 "`CREATE TABLE` Syntax" of the Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html):

> `KEY` is normally a synonym for INDEX. The key attribute `PRIMARY KEY` can also be specified as just `KEY` when given in a column definition. This was implemented for compatibility with other database systems.

(The first sentence is what applies in your case; so it's just creating an index named `vendor_id` on `notes.vendor_id`.)